# Java SWT: How to indicate a menu item is selected

Tags: java, swt, menu

Using SWT, what is the common way to indicate that a menu item (from a taskbar menu) is the currently active selection? Checkmark? Bold? How is this done with code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [CHECK](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#CHECK) style during instantiation:

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CHECK);
```

Use [getSelection](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/MenuItem.html#getSelection()) to check status:

```
boolean isSelected = menuItem.getSelection();
```

Answer (score 4):

[org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/MenuItem.html) **setSelection(true)** / **getSelection()**

The style of the selection depends on the style of the menu item: CHECK, CASCADE, PUSH, RADIO, SEPARATOR, as in:

[image]
<sub>(source: [developpez.com](http://jmdoudoux.developpez.com/cours/developpons/java/images/swt047.png))</sub>   [image]
<sub>(source: [developpez.com](http://jmdoudoux.developpez.com/cours/developpons/java/images/swt046.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuItem.getSelection()
```